# How to write unit tests for functions in python for a task manager program?

Tags: python, unit-testing, project

I'm writing a program in python to create a task manger. I've completed it but now I want to write unit tests for all the functions I used in the program. The functions are interconnected and they have to do with file handling which is confusing for me as they hardly return anything, so there's no way for me to assert the result. No matter the tests I write, it passes them all even if they are obviously wrong. These are the tests I've written so far:

```
#the task manager program
import datetime

def user_information(ussnm, pssd):
    name = input("Enter your name: \n")
    address = input("Enter your address: \n")
    age = input("Enter your age: \n")
    ussnm_ = f"{ussnm}'s tasks.txt"
    with open(ussnm_, 'a') as f:
        f.write(pssd)
        f.write(f"\nName: {name}\n")
        f.write(f"Address: {address}\n")
        f.write(f"Age: {age}\n")
        f.write("\n")


def signup():
    print("Create a new account")
    username = input("Enter your Username: \n")
    password = "" #input("Enter your Password: \n")
    while True:
        if len(password) < 8:
            print("Password too short. Try again.")
            password = input("Enter your Password: \n")
        else:
            user_information(username, password)
            print("Account created successfully. Log in to your account")
            login()


def login():
    user_name = input("Enter your username: ")
    pass_word = input("Enter the password: ")
    try:
        usernm = f"{user_name}'s tasks.txt"
        with open(usernm, 'r') as f:
            #p is the saved password
            #list index out of range
            p = f.readlines(0)[0]
        if pass_word.strip() == p.strip():
            print("Log in successful!")
            response = input("Choose: \n 1 To view your list of tasks \n 2 To add task \n 3 To update task status \n 4 View task status \n")
            #To view list of task
            if response  == '1':
                view_data(usernm)
            #To add task
            elif response == '2':
                task_information(usernm)
            elif response == '3':
                task_update(usernm)
            elif response == '4':
                task_update_viewer(usernm)
            else:
                print("No such option. Try again")
                login()
        else:
            print("Your username or password is incorrect")
            login()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        login()

#To view list of task
def view_data(username):
    with open(username, 'r') as v:
        print(v.read())

#To add task
def task_information(username):
    no_of_task = int(input("How many tasks do you want to add? "))
    with open(username, 'a') as t:
        #doesn't keep asking for tasks for the number of times inputted, only asks once
        for i in range(1, no_of_task+1):
            task = input("Enter a new task: ")
            target = input("How much time do you want to use on this task? ")
            tas = f"Task {str(i)}:"
            tar = f"Target {str(i)}:"

            t.write(f"{tas} {task} \n")
            t.write(f"{tar} {target} \n")
            #to stop adding tasks
            stop = input("Press space bar to stop adding tasks. Otherwise, press enter: ")
            if stop == " ":
                print("Task(s) added")
                break

#To update tasks
def task_update(username):
    #adding a weird name (mayo's tasks.txt's tasks)
    username = f"{username}'s tasks.txt"
    task_completed = input("Enter completed tasks: ")
    task_pending = input("Enter pending tasks: ")
    task_ongoing = input("Enter ongoing tasks: ")

    with open(username, 'a') as up:
        date = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        up.write(f"{date} \n")
        up.write(f"COMPLETED TASK: \n{task_completed} \n")
        up.write(f"ONGOING TASK: \n{task_ongoing} \n")
        up.write(f"PENDING TASKS: \n{task_pending} \n")


def task_update_viewer(username):
    username = f"{username}'s tasks.txt"
    with open(username, 'r') as up_view:
        print(up_view.read())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Welcome to your task manager")
    try:
        a = int(input("Create new account? Type 0 \nAlready a member? Type 1\n"))
        if a == 0:
            signup()
        elif a == 1:
            login()
        else:
            print("No such option")
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a number")
```

```
#the tests I've written

import os.path
from project import user_information
from project import signup
from project import login
from project import view_data
from project import task_information
from project import task_update
from project import task_update_viewer

def test_user_information():
    def user_information(ussnm, pssd):
        if ussnm == "mayo" and pssd == "mayomikun":
            assert os.path.exists("mayo's tasks.txt") == True

def test_signup():
    def signup():
        username = input("Enter your Username: \n")
        password = input("Enter your Password: \n")
        if username == "mayo" and len(password) == 4:
            assert signup() == login()

def test_login():
    def login():
        user_name = input("Enter your Username: \n")
        pass_word = input("Enter your Password: \n")
        if user_name == "mayo" and pass_word == "mayomikun":
            assert login() == "Log in successful!"
```

Please, help me with this. Thank you.

I tried changing the values to obvious wrong values and the tests were still passed which made me doubt the authencity if the tests.

Comment: These functions don't really look testable in all honesty. They don't `return` any values and rely heavily on user input within the function. You could [`patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) `input` but that won't change a whole lot. Additionally, I'm not sure what's you're attempting to achieve with your tests? From what I can tell, you're just shadowing the functions your testing with new definitions.

Comment: That's what I thought too. The thing is I have to make a program with 3 or functions and test them all. It's a final project, so I wanted to make it a bit more complex than normal programs. If you have any suggestions, I'd be happy to know them. @Axe319